# How to shorten the namespace indentation in C++ header files without using 'using'?

Tags: c++, coding-style, namespaces

If you use namespaces for separation of modules / structurization the nesting and indentation within the the header file increases dramatically. Is there a way to write the following code in a shorter way?

```
namespace A
{
    namespace B
    {
        namespace C
        {
            namespace D
            {
                namespace E
                {
                    template <typename T>
                    public class X
                    {
                        public: ...
```

e.g. like

```
namespace A::B::C::D::E
{
  template<typename T> ...
}
```

in the header file in c++?

Comment: Try to avoid such a deep nesting.

Comment: Is there really a big difference between `namespace A::B::C {` and `namespace A { namespace B { namespace C {`? You don't have to indent everything like you do.

Comment: The [Google C++ Style Guide](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.xml#Namespaces) recommends not indenting namespaces.

Comment: @Fiktik The difference is readablility (which is indeed a weakness of c++)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, that nested namespace syntax has been suggested before at different times and places but isn't valid.

You don't need to indent though

```
namespace A { namespace B { namespace C {
// ...
} } } // namespace A::B::C
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use namespace aliasing. This doesn't work for extending existing namespaces, but rather for easier access.

You can use macros to extend existing namespaces, **but** it you need to do this, you've probably got a deeper namespace hierarchy than you need or want.

Comment: The question was in the context of declaring things in namespaces in headers and you can't use aliases for that as you can't declare things in a namespace alias. And macros? Eurgh.

Comment: Personally, I don't like marcros / preprocessor defines and try to avoid them if possible